# Angular2 property derived of 2 properties

Tags: angular

learning Angular2 so please don't be mean

So let's say my `UserComponent` is exporting a user of type `User`. It gets it from a `UserService` at `ngOnInit`. It has 2 properties called `height` and `weight`.

In my template, I want to display `{{ user.score }}` where `score` is derived from `height` and `weight`. I am using a function that takes `height` and `weight` as parameters and returns score.

My question is, where do I declare `score`? If I do it in the `ngOnInit` loop it doesn't work.

Thank you for helping a beginner

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
user = new User;
charId: number;
private sub: any;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.userId = params['id'];
        this.userService.getUser(this.charId)
            .subscribe(
                (user: User) => {
                    this.user = user
                });
    });
}
}

// and the service

getUser(userId) {
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/user' + userId)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        const user = response.json().obj;
        return user;
    })
    .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}
```

Comment: Can you put your service and component code here?

Comment: I simplified it but here it is

Comment: how do you mean it doesnt work?

Comment: Try out this: `character = new User();` if It's a `class`.

Comment: sorry about the character part, I updated the code so it is consistent

Comment: I need to add something like this.user.score = calcScore(this.user.height, this.user.weight) so I can display {{ user.score }} in my template but I don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment above, try something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.userId = params['id'];
        this.userService.getUser(this.charId)
            .subscribe(
                (user: User) => {
                    this.user = user;
                    this.calcScore(this.user.height, this.user.weight);
                });
    });
}

calcScore(height, weight) {
    this.user.score = YOUR_CALC
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, it works great! If user.weight changes, will user.score be updated as well? Because that is the kind of behaviour I need.

Comment: Yeah it will work, but you need to call `calcScore()` again so onchange `user.weight` value call this. and Please accept answer if it's working.

Comment: Where do I call it again? Do I need to implement onChange?

Comment: First tell how and when `user.weight` will change?

Comment: There is an input field in my template with a two-way binding to user.weight.

Comment: so try like this `<input type="text" name="weight" [ngModel]="user.weight" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" />` and in method `onChange(e)` you will get data and call that function OR if you have submit button there also you can do on submit call.

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the score when you have the data you need for that, which is after the subscription returns

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
score : number;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.userId = params['id'];
        this.userService.getUser(this.charId)
            .subscribe(
                (user: User) => {
                    this.user = user
                    this.user.score = calcScore(this.user.height, this.user.weight)
                });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
user = new User;
charId: number;
private sub: any;


constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.userId = params['id'];
        this.userService.getUser(this.charId)
            .subscribe(
                (user: User) => {
                    this.user = user;
this.user.score=calcScore(this.user.height, this.user.weight);//do it here
                });
    });
}
}

// and the service

getUser(userId) {
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/user' + userId)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        const user = response.json().obj;
        return user;
    })
    .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
}
```

In your template display as:

```
{{user?.score}}
```

since user will be set through async operation,it will come after view is generated.
Angular will set it after detecting changes